# Google Compute Engine - Project invitation not found

Tags: google-compute-engine

Under "permissions" I added 9 members to my Google Developers Console project, all with edit rights. Their email addresses are all in our corporate Gmail domain. This works fine, but one person gets the following error message when following the rsvp link in the invitation email:

```
"The specified invitation was not found."
```

I removed the invitation, waited a while and sent the invitation again, but to no avail. If this particular person goes to the project page they get the error message: "This project is unavailable."

What's going on?

Answer (score 3):

As long as this person hasn't accept the invitation, this user won't be able to see the project.

Have your user to open the invitation on a different browser or if you are using Chrome, try incognito window.

Test with a new user, if this new user is able to join the project but not the person with this issue, contact Google directly.

Mary